# React Native: BackHandler.exitApp() can't kill the app's process

Tags: react-native

When i see the native code.

`BackHandler.exitApp()` will invoke android's `onBackPressed()`

Why not invoke `System.exit(0)` to exit the app and kill process?

Comment: BTW Where did you check code of `BackHandler.exitApp()`

Answer (score 1):

You may use [react-native-exit-app](https://github.com/wumke/react-native-exit-app),
and replace `BackHandler.exitApp()` with:

`import RNExitApp from 'react-native-exit-app';
...
RNExitApp.exitApp();
...`

Comment: `RNExitApp.exitApp()` still kip app in task, How to kill it?

Comment: use android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true" in <activity> of AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @Azarsa I can see rest react native apps using recents but still able to exits completely and starts with a splash screen

Answer (score 0):

> Why not invoke System.exit(0) to exit the app and kill process?

`System.exit(0)` is a bad approach to kill your application process. Android manage it in a awesome style. This made them to call `onBackPressed()`

Comment: But in my app.Some phone will start a new activity when i press android's home key.So i want to kill application process.

Comment: @PrivateZ I am not sure, see if you can override `onBackPressed` method and call `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());`

Comment: Thank you. I find this plan just now.