# BackHandler.exitApp() is not closing the services of react-native android app

Tags: android, react-native, service, redux, reduce

When I am using `BackHandler.exitApp()` to close the app and not removing the app from task manager window of the android, when I am again opening the app, it seems before it starts the service init, it start to call service functions. 
So as a result, I am doing init of `this.db = new Datastore({ filename: dbPath, autoload: true, ...options });` , But before it happens the database service is already trying to use `this.db`, so, as a result, it is saying `this.db` as `undefined`.

Can anyone tell me how can I do the init first and then start the services everytime I open the app? Or how can I exit a react native app with completely kill all the tasks?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by this module `react-native-exit-app` - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-exit-app

It closes the app completely.

But it would be great if someone can explain the question.

Comment: It seems that this is what BackHandler.exitApp() is supposed to do...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44694356/react-native-backhandler-exitapp-cant-kill-the-apps-process